# Does Windows 7 have .NET 4 installed by default?

Tags: windows-7, .net-framework

I offered software where .NET 4.0 is needed and promised, that Windows 7 already comes with this framework. If not, the user can use the integrated "Windows Update" function to install the framework. My client said to me there is no Framework on Windows 7 Professional installed already. What are details about the situation of Windows 7 and is there an option to install .NET by using the update function of Windows 7?

Comment: It is installed by default.  It can be removed.  Have your client install it.

Comment: @Ramhound - your comment conflicts with top voted answer below

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Windows 7 does not come with .NET 4 preloaded, but if you run Windows Update to get it up to date, it will be installed.

**UPDATE**:

Checking my update history over again, and yes it's offered as an update, but only after I updated the computer to SP1.

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer. The answer from SkyBeam says, that only 3.5 will be installed and 4.0 needs to be installed manually. are you 100% sure 4.0 comes with updates?

Comment: The attached picture in the answer shows that it comes as an update, but only after I installed SP1, which may be the case for other Windows 7 computers as well.

Comment: I can confirm that .NET framework 4 comes with updates. But maybe not with the first bunch of updates. For me it required about 3 reboots and 4 WU cycles to make it show up (fresh Win7 installation with SP1 integrated into setup media). The hint about SP1 might be important too. SP1 is still not applied on all Win7 nodes and therefore .NET 4 might not be deployed on a wide user base. I would recommend to bundle an application requiring it with the .NET 4 client profile redistribution package.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now there is no more confusion on my side! Great!

Comment: Also of note: If you only install "Recommended" updates and not "Optional" updates, you only get .NET 4.0 *Client* Profile -- not the *Full* profile -- though: with .NET 4.5.x recently becoming a Recommended update that's not as relevant anymore (because 4.5.x replaces 4.0 Full Profile anyway).

Comment: Yes all versions of the .Net framework are coming as updates. On a test VM with win update running, as stated above they come in the rounds. 2nd round had 4.5.2 in the list and checked, had 4.6.1 in the list but un-checked, will add anther comment when update is finished.

Answer (score 18):

Windows 7 (SP1) comes with the following .NET frameworks 1.0, 1.1, 2.0, 3.0 and 3.5 support AFAIK. If you need .NET Framework 4.0 support then your clients need to download at least [Microsoft .NET Framework 4 client profile](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=e5ad0459-cbcc-4b4f-97b6-fb17111cf544).

I have just verified Windows update on a clean Windows 7 Home Premium installation. Directly after installation, Windows Update offers a security update for .NET Framework 3.5.1. But no .NET Framework 4.0 is offered by Windows Update at first run of Windows Update. I am going to install the patches provided first and then report if .NET Framework 4.0 is offered at a later stage.

Update: I just entered the second update round on my VM, and now I am offered six important updates only. Still no .NET framework 4.

Update 2: I just had to do another two rounds of Windows Updates and now "Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile for Windows 7" is provided through Windows Update.

So yes, it seems to be automatically deployed if Windows Update is enabled. Either you need to make sure really all updates are applied or you just go for the download link provided above.

Comment: After a few update sequences, I had .NET 4.0 in my update history. So I guess you need to run Windows Update a few times.

Comment: You could be right. I am using a softwrae deployment system which assures that .NET framework 4 is deployed to my clients. But I think you're right that after some update sessions it gets offered. I am just about to verify it. At least on first WU run it did not show up yet.

Comment: I checked my update history again, it came only after I installed SP1.

Comment: Good point about SP1, rewarded it by voting your answer.

Comment: 1.0 and 1.1 are *not* installed on Windows 7.  1.x apps can be run on the 2.0 runtime, and most do without issue.  However, there were breaking API changes between 1.x and 2.0, and 1.x apps can trip over the behavioral changes.  That said, .NET 1.x apps are very rare.

Comment: @afrazier: Thanks for clarification. I am not a .NET expert at all; just had a clean Win7 SP1 installation and looked at %SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework and found the versions there I've listed. But seems to be correct that 1.x folders are basically empty. However I've never seen any .NET 1.x application in real life.

Comment: To be clear though -- this is only the Client Profile version -- not the full profile version. -- This is an important distinction.

Answer (score 1):

No, it comes with `.NET Framework 3.5.1` according to https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/astebner/mailbag-what-version-of-the-net-framework-is-included-in-what-version-of-the-os